# What was data tainting in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

While reading about the [`navigator`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_navigator.asp) object in JavaScript I ran into a [`taintEnabled()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_nav_taintenabled.asp) function, as well as similar `taint()` and `untaint()` functions, referring to something called "data-tainting".

Googling around net and Stack Overflow show some possible reference to Perl language, but none about JavaScript. I wonder, what is data-taining and how to use these functions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Data Tainting (or [Taint Checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking)) is a language feature wherein user-input data is flagged as tainted, a flag that propagates to all data derived from this input. As a result, code can implement runtime assertions to ensure security critical code is not being called using tainted data (ie prevent SQLi, XSS type attacks).

Whilst Netscape implemented it in the browser in v3 and v4, support for it sadly never materialized elsewhere, so @trejder is absolutely right that it should be avoided in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my apparently wrong answer. Even though we're talking about solution abandoned years ago, I'd like to see correct answer, so I re-picked and accepted yours.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, there aren't many sources in the Internet about data-tainting, as it seems to be a long forgotten, deprecated technique and topic. But I found out an interesting reading on this  on [findmeat.org](http://www.findmeat.org/tutorials/javascript/x361556.htm). For the `Navigator.taintEnabled()` method it says that (various parts cited, some text shortened):

> The data-tainting support was a short-lived means of sending data back to a server. The security implications became unworkable and the whole data tainting idea was deprecated. The functionality was removed in JavaScript version 1.2. This method is only supported in order to prevent scripts from crashing. This functionality is highly deprecated and you can expect it to cause run-time exceptions in future. You should seek to try and remove it to prevent run-time errors in the future.

It seems that nowadays few browsers support this function (and similar, mentioned) and that it should not be used under any circumstance. Even if a browser implements this at all, it should return the value false for this method, always.

Comment: Tainting is *not* a mechanism to send data back to the server. Your source is just plain wrong here I'm afraid. It would be used to validate that data being sent back to the server was not derived from unsanitised user input. See my answer.